# Bundle ID app for submitting to the App Store

Tags: app-store

I have an issue that confuses me a little.

In order to submit my app to the App Store I have to enter the Bundle ID Suffix. As you may know, the Bundle ID gets the exact name of the Bundle ID Suffix (What you write on Bundle ID Suffix is also written automatically in Bundle ID)

Now what I don't know is if I need to write:

- com.mycompany.myapp

  ```
      or
  ```
- 7I8UIRE4L9.com.mycompany.myapp  (7I8UIRE4L9 being the app ID that was given to me when I                created the provisioning profile for the app)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to enter the reverse DNS portion of your bundle ID into the iTunes Connect submission portal.  Not the random-looking seed portion of the app ID.

(Make sure you replaced the "mycompany" portion of the string with the name of your company.)

Comment: just the answer i was looking for ;) I already did it that way and the binary went through without problems. Harder than coding is the fact you have to deal with, IDs, provisioning certificates, correct code signing, etc. Well thanks for the answer and hope to get my app in the App Store soon. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Better you select your project, go to info. select custon ios target properties.in bundle identifier write your bundle name.Make sure that itunes bundle suffix should be match with this ...
hope this will help you..